# How to optmize ssis package when data is huge

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a table TABLE_SRC having 3 million records and 20 columns in one of the SQL server DB 
 I want to load data in same structure table TABLE_DEST in a different server and  in SQL server DB 
 I just created one oledb source that would pull data from TABLE_SRC and then use oledbcommand to delete existing data from TABLE_DEST
 and then use oledbdestination to map and load data from TABLE_SRC to TABLE_DEST.

But this process is taking too much of time, as data is huge I understand that it would take time but can I optimize or use some best practices to load data in this case.

Comment: Is making a backup of the source DB and restoring it to another server an option?

Comment: No, I have to create SSIS package for this and that would run on an hourly basis. This is client requirement.

Comment: @hieko you can explore `sql server destination` instead of oledb, if it suits the situation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388925/sql-sever-destination-vs-ole-db-destination

Comment: I think SQL server destination should be used when the database is local for remote DB oledb is the best choice.

Comment: You are deleting the whole destination table and inserting the whole source table every time?   why?   Do all the rows in the table change all the time?

Comment: yes data would be change every day for new  market and there is no point checking data if it exists because that would be useless in this particular case and also slow.

Comment: Question 1: Is there a reason you cannot truncate the target table prior to loading it? For example, Key 1 is in yesterday's data but today it is not and the target table needs to still have Key 1 in it plus the most current data for Key 2- 3M.  Question 2 - can you create a second table on the remote server? Question 3 - How do you determine if there is a change between data (might not be applicable based on Q1)

Comment: ans 1: i am deleting all data before insertion.
ans 2: doesn't get it 
ans 3: i dont want to determine changes beacuse i know everything would be new and that's why i am deleting all data 

truncate is subject to rights on some server where specific user may not have all the rights to truncate data thats why i am using delete

Comment: Well if you're concerned with performance why would you delete instead of truncate if truncate is an option?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use OLE DB Command. It performs singleton operations meaning that you will issue 3M deletes on the remote server. Instead, design your control flow as an `Execute SQL Task` followed by a `Data Flow Task`. In the comments you've indicated that permissions are going to be an issue since you cannot issue a truncate table command. Instead, the Execute SQL Task will need a `DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable;` to drain all the data.
2. Ensure that you are using the Fast Load option with the OLE DB Destination. This will lock the target table for optimal load patterns. You likely want to experiment with the max rows commit size (name approximate). Default will be 2 billion or so, try starting out at 50000. This commits the data in smaller batches than everything all at once. This can help the target server get some breathing room as you firehose all the data into it.

Other things that will kill your performance:

- Bad network
- Additional transformations in the data flow (I assume OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination)
- Running the package within Visual Studio itself
- Running the package in 32 bit mode
- Poorly tuned target server
- Don't deal with LOB data types (image/object/(n)text/(n)varchar(max)/varbinary(max)) in the data flow task

Beyond that, without more detail that's about the advice I can give you to make this go fast. 3 Million rows should be nothing to send every hour.

Comment: Your suggestions help me now I have use execute SQL task and then DFT.
But in executesql task, i want to use 29 table as delete but if any of the table insertions get fail inside dft I want to rollback the process for a particular table.

How I can achieve this>please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

in `oledb destination` under `data access mode` try using choice having `fast load` (in your case `table or view fast load`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete and insert date. Use SQL change tracking with SSIS package to insert incremental data.