# Deployment location for SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have this scenario which has to be solved by SSIS:

- I have multiple instances of the same DB (they may be on different servers)
- I have one Master DB on a different server
- now I need to transfer data from these different instances to Master DB using SSIS

My question is - where exactly SSIS needs to be installed? On Master DB server? On each of the source DB servers? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be installed on the server it will be executed from, it can be a seperate server from master or clients or anyone of them.

Note that if you want to perform Bulk insert operation, then you should install it on master server.

Check the following links to get some insights:

- [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)#choosing-between-bulk-load-methods)
- [SQL Sever Destination vs OLE DB Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388925/sql-sever-destination-vs-ole-db-destination)

Comment: So if I understand it correctly - if I install SSIS on Master DB server, the license is covered by SQL Server license and then this kind of solution can connect automatically to source DBs. Without a need to install / enable SSIS on source servers? Is that correct?

Comment: @GeorgeRosword 100% true

Comment: Thanks. This concludes the subject.